# Segmentation fault in function get_dimensions() when scanning variable into a structure pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, structure

I've spent upwards of 12 hours straight trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and have been working on this program on and off for about a week now. Assignment is due early tomorrow morning, any help at all would be appreciated, I'm really desperate to pass.

When debugging, I found that the program breaks when I scan for data for p_rectangle->length/width, I'm sure it has something to do with how I set up main() or memory allocation, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks guys.

```
//**********************************************************************
//*                                                                    *
//* This program calculates and prints the area and perimeter of a     *
//* rectangle and then draws a representation of the proportionality   *
//* between length and width as a rectangle with a minimum length      *
//* and width of 1.                                                    *
//*                                                                    *
//**********************************************************************

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//**********************************************************************
//*                         Symbolic Constants                         *
//**********************************************************************
#define COURSE_NAME              "Object-Oriented Programming and Design"
                                         // Assigned course name
#define COURSE_NUMBER            "CS246" // PCC assigned course number
#define MINIMUM_RECTANGLE_LENGTH 1.0     // Program preset range maximum
#define MINIMUM_RECTANGE_WIDTH   1.0     // Program preset range minimum
#define PROGRAM_NUMBER           "1"       // Teacher assigned program number
#define RECTANGLE_BORDER         "*"     // Rectangle border character
#define RECTANGLE_CENTER         " "     // Rectangle center character

//**********************************************************************
//*                         Program Structures                         *
//**********************************************************************
// Measurements specifications of a rectangle
struct rectangle
{
   float area,
         length,
         perimeter,
         width;
};

//**********************************************************************
//*                        Function Prototypes                         *
//**********************************************************************
void print_heading ();
// Print the program heading

void get_dimensions(struct rectangle *p_rectangle);
// Get the rectangle length and heigth and calculate the area and perimeter

void draw_rectangle(float length, float width);
// Draw a picture of a rectangle

void print_rectangle_specifications(struct rectangle *p_rectangle);
// Print the area, perimeter, width, and length

//**********************************************************************
//*                           Main Function                            *
//**********************************************************************
int main()
{
   struct rectangle *p_rectangle; // Points to measurements specifications of a rectangle

   // Print the program heading
   print_heading ();

   // Get the rectangle length and height and calculate the area and perimeter
   get_dimensions(p_rectangle);

   // Draw a picture of a rectangle
   draw_rectangle(p_rectangle->length, p_rectangle->width);

   // Print the area, perimeter, width, and length
   print_rectangle_specifications(p_rectangle);

   // Say goodbye and terminate the program
   cout << "\n\nThanks for drawing a rectangle today ;)";
   cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n";
   free(p_rectangle);
   return 0;
}
//**********************************************************************
//*                     Print the program heading                      *
//**********************************************************************
void print_heading()
{
   cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n" << COURSE_NUMBER
        << " "            << COURSE_NAME
        << " - Program "  << PROGRAM_NUMBER;
   cout << "\n\n             This program draws a rectangle";
   cout << "\n             ==============================";

   return;
}

//**********************************************************************
//*             Get the length and width of your rectangle             *
//**********************************************************************
void get_dimensions(struct rectangle *p_rectangle)
{
   cout << "\n\nEnter the rectangle length now: ";
    cin >> p_rectangle->length;
   cout << "\nEnter the rectangle width here: ";
    cin >> p_rectangle->width;

   p_rectangle->area      = (p_rectangle->length * p_rectangle->width);
   p_rectangle->perimeter = (p_rectangle->length + p_rectangle->width) * 2;

   return;
}

//**********************************************************************
//*                   Draw a picture of the rectangle                  *
//**********************************************************************
void draw_rectangle(float length, float width)
{
   int columns,
      i_length = (int)length,
      i_width  = (int)width,
      rows;

   // Checks if rectangle length and width is less than the minimum length
   // and width
   if ((i_length < MINIMUM_RECTANGLE_LENGTH) && (i_width < MINIMUM_RECTANGE_WIDTH))
   {
      cout << "\n\n\nA " << i_length << " by " << i_width;
      cout << " is too small to draw.";
      cout << "\nIt must be at least size " << MINIMUM_RECTANGLE_LENGTH;
      cout << " by " << MINIMUM_RECTANGLE_LENGTH << " (length by width).";
   }
   else
   {
      // Scales the length and width of the rectangle on a 1-to-1 scale
      columns = i_length * 1.5,
         rows = i_width;

      // Prints the rectangle message
      cout << "\n\nHere is a picture of your rectangle";

      // Prints the top row of the rectangle
      for (int top_row = 1; top_row <= columns; top_row++)
         cout << RECTANGLE_BORDER;

      // Prints all middle rows of the rectangle
      for (int middle_row = 1; middle_row <= columns - 2; middle_row++)
         cout << "\n" << RECTANGLE_BORDER;``
         for (int middle_column = 1; middle_column <= rows; middle_column++)
         {
            cout    << RECTANGLE_CENTER;
            if (rows == middle_column)
               cout << RECTANGLE_BORDER;
         }

      // Prints the bottom row of the rectangle
      if (i_width > 1)
         for (int bottom_row = 1; bottom_row <= columns; bottom_row++)
            cout << RECTANGLE_BORDER;
   }

   return;
}

//**********************************************************************
//*              Print the calculations of the rectangle               *
//**********************************************************************
void print_rectangle_specifications(struct rectangle *p_rectangle)
{
   cout << "\n\nThe rectangle specifications are:";
   cout << "\n        Length = " << p_rectangle->length    << " units";
   cout << "\n         Width = " << p_rectangle->width     << " units";
   cout << "\n          Area = " << p_rectangle->area      << " sq. units";
   cout << "\n     Perimeter = " << p_rectangle->perimeter << " units";
   return;
}
```

Comment: `struct rectangle *p_rectangle;` This is an uninitialized pointer. First attempt to use it will result in undefined behavior, and that's precisely what happens in `get_dimensions`.

Comment: `struct rectangle *p_rectangle; // Points to measurements specifications of a rectangle` this is wrong. that pointer doesnt point to anything as it is not initialized

Comment: also you really should use new/delete in C++ not malloc/free (unless you have a really good reason to use malloc/free and know what youre doing). although that being said you should avoid newing memory manually

Comment: @Borgleader Thank man, I appreciate the critique

Comment: Tip: In C++ stay far away from `#define` for constants and instead use `const`, like `const char* PROGRAM_NUMBER = "1"` or `const double MINIMUM_RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 1.0` so that important type information is retained. This can also aid significantly in debugging since it's obvious where those values come from.

Comment: When you're debugging pay careful attention to what the pointers are set to. In a debug build you might see them set to `0xF0F0F0...` or `0xDEADBEEF` or junk like that which is a hint that value is not properly initialized. Even better, since C++ doesn't depend on pointers like C does, avoid using them whenever possible. Use references and make your objects cheap to copy.

Answer (score 1):

In main():

> struct rectangle *p_rectangle;

There are two problems here:

1. You don't need to specify "struct" again when declaring a variable of type rectangle.
2. You should always define a variable before you use it. In the case with pointers, you can allocate it on the free store.

So, the solution is this:

```
rectangle *p_rectangle = new rectangle;
```